# Access different relationship in different child controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

In rails 5 I have a model FatherModel with lots of relationships.
I need to have a controller (and views) for every related model.
The views are different but the controller is mostly similar, so I'm thinking about using inheritance.

I have a FatherController
and multiple child controllers A, B, C...

In every child controller needs to be lines like:

```
@a = @father_model.relationship_a
```

How can i put this in the FatherController ? I'm thinking something like

```
@model = @father_model.send(:relationship_name)
```

And declare `:relationship_name` in the childs model.
Is this the only way?

Also, there is some way to use `@a` instead of a generic `@model` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Ruby is a dynamic language, it allows you to implement such kind of magic.

At first, you can get the name of the current controller using method [controller_name](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Metal/controller_name/class)

Thus, the following line:

```
@a = @father_model.relationship_a
```

Can be rewritten to something like (depends on the real names of your controller and associations):

```
@a = @father_model.send("relationship_#{controller_name}")
```

> Also, there is some way to use `@a` instead of a generic `@model`?

Yes, you can define instance variables dynamically using [instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) method:

```
instance_variable_set(:"@#{controller_name}", @father_model.send("relationship_#{controller_name}"))
```

But again, the code above assumes that you actually have controller with a name `A` and relationship with a name `relationship_a`